# Relative links in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my templates I want to use relative routes. Currently I have absolute paths in my anchor `href`'s, which is suboptimal

```
<a href="/#/dashboard/settings">Settings</a>
```

How can I rewrite this to be a relative navigation (in this relative to `dashboard`)?

It should work with hashbang and html5 history api routes (whichever AngularJS uses or falls back to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can rewrite it to use relative navigation.  How is relative going to work if you want to link to `/user/profile`, but your user is on `/dashboard/settings`.  If the main navigation links to simply `profile` (relative), it's going to go to `/dashboard/profile`, which I'm assuming is not what you want.

Why is relative pathing so important in your application?  Anything more than savings keystrokes?

Comment: Is there at least a way to tell angular to automatically replace the `/#/` prefix with `/` if HTML5 routing is available (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, if you use the `$locationProvider` with `.html5Mode(true)`: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: I already use that, but it doesn't substitute the hash, just escapes it `/#%2Fdashboard%2Fsettings`.

Comment: Maybe you've misconfigured it?  Here's a simple example: http://home.langdonx.com/location-test/ In Chrome, you'll see nice Urls, in IE9 you'll see hashbang.

Answer (score 2):

Within your controller you can look at the `$routeParams` and build a **base** url to operate from.

From there your templates can operate against `"{{baseUrl}}/relative/to/scope/baseUrl"`

And urls built within your code can go to `$scope.baseUrl + /relative/to/scope/baseUrl";`

It's not exactly "relative" but it does solve the issue of allowing urls refining other urls without having to hard-code the hierarchy and worry about routeparams that are variables and such.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your angular version, but in my 1.2.18, when you set

```
<base href="/base"></base>
```

and whenever in your  element href, you start with "relative/to/you/url", then your link will point to "/base/relative/to/you/url":

```
<a href="relative/to/you/url"></a>
```

NOTE: I've turned on the html5 api mode for $locationProvider:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

EDIT: See MDN document for `<base>` tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I found this works:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
    rewriteLinks: false
});
```